# Python dict dict

Tags: python, dict

Есть два dict. Нужно пройтись с начало по goods, через его ID зайти store и там умножить quantity и price на ID=12345, а на ID=23456 с начало умножить quantity и price на одном dict и плюсовать их:

```
goods = {
    'Lampa': '12345',
    'Stol': '23456'
}

store = {
    '12345': [
        {
            'quantity': 27,
            'price': 42
        },
    ],
    '23456': [
        {
            'quantity': 22,
            'price': 510
        },
        {
            'quantity': 32,
            'price': 520
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: а где   вопрос ? ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summs = [sum(v['quantity']*v['price'] for v in store[goods[key]]) for key in goods]
pairs = [(goods[key], sum(v['quantity']*v['price'] for v in store[goods[key]])) for key in goods]

new_dict = {key: sum(v['quantity']*v['price'] for v in store[goods[key]]) for key in goods}
new_dict1 = {goods[key]: sum(v['quantity']*v['price'] for v in store[goods[key]]) for key in goods}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Нужно узнать цену каждого товара. Например, ID(12345)=Lampa. Чтобы узнать общее Lampa= quantity x price

Comment: @Handsome_777 в `summs` хранятся общие стоимости, в `pairs` - пары: ("id" из `goods`, его суммарная стоимость).

Comment: @Handsome_777 добавил еще варианты со словарями

Answer (score 2):

вы сначала задачу более прямым языком поставьте :)

как я понял задачу

```
goods = {
    'Lampa': '12345',
    'Stol': '23456'
}

store = {
    '12345': [
        {
            'quantity': 27,
            'price': 42
        },
    ],
    '23456': [
        {
            'quantity': 22,
            'price': 510
        },
        {
            'quantity': 32,
            'price': 520
        },
    ],
}

for obj in goods.items():
  if obj[1] in store:
    res = sum(elem['quantity'] * elem['price'] for elem in store[obj[1]])]
    print(obj[0], res)
```